# use d3 with node.js / EJS rendering

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I'm trying to build a simple example on Cloud 9 using node.js and D3, but having some issues rendering the chart.

I have a simple view in a `chart.ejs` file and have attempted to do an include of the d3.v3.js and d3.layout.js files.   However, I keep getting `Uncaught Syntax Error:  Unexpected token <`  when the d3 include files are reached.

So a couple of questions:

1. Has anyone been able to use D3 with EJS?  I've seen some Jade examples, but not EJS.
2. Is using the `<script>` tag the appropriate way to use D3 with EJS rendering?
3. Any good examples out there using D3 and node.js?

Would appreciate any thoughts / comments?

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to node.js and D3, so I may need some basic direction.

EDIT:  here's the `chart.ejs` code.  It has something to do with the script include.  When I try to include locally like below, it throws the unexpected token error.  But when I refer to the include from a download location, it seems to work.  It may be a C9 thing, not sure though.  Curious if someone else has run across this in C9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // Your beautiful D3 code will go here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no reason why it should not work with ejs. Can you show the chart.ejs. Maybe we can point out the problem.

Comment: chart.ejs noted above.